# Create powershell parameter default value is current directory

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm hoping to create a parameter who's default value is the 'current directory' (`.`).

For example, the `Path` parameter of `Get-ChildItem`:

```
PS> Get-Help Get-ChildItem -Full
```

> -Path 
>           Specifies a path to one or more locations. Wildcards are permitted. The default location is the current
>           directory (.).
>
> ```
>     Required?                    false
>     Position?                    1
>     Default value                Current directory
>     Accept pipeline input?       true (ByValue, ByPropertyName)
>     Accept wildcard characters?  true
> ```

I created a function with a `Path` parameter that accepts input from the pipeline, with a default value of `.`:

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Does something with paths supplied via pipeline.
.PARAMETER Path
Specifies a path to one or more locations. Wildcards are permitted. The default location is the current directory (.).
#>
Function Invoke-PipelineTest {

    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipeline=$True,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$True)]
        [string[]]$Path='.'
    )
    BEGIN {}
    PROCESS {
      $Path | Foreach-Object {
        $Item = Get-Item $_
        Write-Host "Item: $Item"
      }
    }
    END {}
}
```

However, the `.` isn't interpreted as the 'current directory' in help:

```
PS> Get-Help Invoke-PipelineTest -Full
```

> -Path 
>           Specifies a path to one or more locations. Wildcards are permitted. The default location is the current directory (.).
>
> ```
>     Required?                    false
>     Position?                    1
>     Default value                .
>     Accept pipeline input?       true (ByValue, ByPropertyName)
>     Accept wildcard characters?  false
> ```

What's the right way to set the `Path` parameter's default value to the current directory?

Incidentally, where does one set the `Accept wildcard character` property?

Comment: Are you sure that isn't all just function-internal magic and a literal default value of "Current directory"? (I assume it isn't that silly and is something explicit but I also assume you likely can't replicate that in powershell directly.)

Comment: I suppose that is possible, but that seems sloppy to me.  Would that value (`Current directory`) change based on the Windows localization?

Comment: I assume that string is localized regardless of how this is implemented internally. That being said I don't expect a comparison against that value is used internally. I expect a "was a valid value given" test is used since `$null` isn't meaningful there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `PSDefaultValue` attribute to define custom description for default value. Use `SupportsWildcards` attribute to mark parameter as `Accept wildcard characters?`.

```powershell
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Does something with paths supplied via pipeline.
.PARAMETER Path
Specifies a path to one or more locations. Wildcards are permitted. The default location is the current directory (.).
#>
Function Invoke-PipelineTest {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipeline=$True,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$True)]
        [PSDefaultValue(Help='Description for default value.')]
        [SupportsWildcards()]
        [string[]]$Path='.'
    )
}
```

Comment: I take it Microsoft couldn't be bothered to update the documentation? *\*sigh\**

Comment: [Relevant](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/06/14/new-v3-language-features.aspx).

Comment: I'll take that as a "yes". ;)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I does not work at Microsoft, so I can not answer for them. Probably, you can bother them by filling ticket in [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell).